# What are the constraints for lacking encoder support in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, codec

According to the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Video-Codecs), there are several video and audio codecs with missing encoder support.

Is this typically because:

**A**) The encoder is copyright protected.

**B**) The encoder implementation is unknown (closed-source).

**C**) No one has so far needed or wanted to implement an FFmpeg version of the encoder.

From reading [FFmpeg License and Legal Considerations](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html) it is not clear to me whether **A** is a concern or not for adding a new encoder to FFmpeg. If **C** is the case and **A** and **B** are not a problem, is my only option to get support for a missing encoder in FFmpeg to implement it myself or can I raise a suggestion to a developer somewhere for upcoming features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, some combination of **B** and **C**.

That License Consideration link applies to redistributing ffmpeg binaries, not to adding encoder interfaces or implementations.